# C# ProcessStart WITHOUT Admin Rights

Tags: c#, process, admin-rights

I'm running a program coded in C# where it runs some commands using the code below:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Microvirt\\EmuManager.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "guestproperty enumerate Emu";

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
return output;
```

Since my application is running **with** Admin Rights, when I run the code above it uses the admin rights on it, but, for some reason, EmuManager.exe does **NOT** work if running with admin rights.

So I need a way to run that command **without** admin rights from my C# application that **is** running with admin rights and get its output.

Comment: Are you sure it is having admin privileges that is causing the problem?
  Have you tried setting the `WorkingDirectory` property of your `startInfo` to "C:\\Program Files\\Microvirt"?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yes I'm sure, Micorvirt support sent me an email talking about that, since I was always running the commands with admin rights and getting errors, then they said that without admin rights it was working, so I'm trying to find an workaround.

Comment: @AleksAndreev The code in the link seems to work, but it's not possible to use arguments in the process and read its output as I could test.